# ngFor list do not print empty value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I receive data (for card) which I further populate as a list:

```
[{"id":20,"responsibilities":[{"id":39,"attribute":"Name","action":"","card":20},{"id":40,"attribute":"ISBN","action":"","card":20},{"id":41,"attribute":"Genre","action":"","card":20},{"id":42,"attribute":"","action":"Purchase","card":20}],"collaborators":[],"thing":"Book"}]
```

I am populating two lists as following:

```
   <h6>Attributes</h6>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of card.responsibilities">
      <div *ngIf="item.attribute">{{item.attribute}}</div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <h6>Actions</h6>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of card.responsibilities">
       <div *ngIf="item.action">{{item.action}}</div>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </ion-col>
```

which looks like following:

[image]

I do not want to print items which have empty values i.e. in the first list if attribute is empty string "" or in the second list if the action is an empty string "". Right now those values are also printed in both the lists.

How to fix this? *ngIf as I tried has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `*ngIf` is inside your `*ngFor` on the `<li>` element, which means it will still create an `<li>` element for every `item of card.responsibilities`, and the `<div>` inside it won't exist if `item.action` evaluates as false. Instead, put the `*ngIf` on the `<li>` element itself like this:

```
<ul>
  <span *ngFor="let item of card.responsibilities">
    <li *ngIf="item.action">
      {{item.action}}
    </li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

This way, an `<li>` element is only created if `item.action` evaluates to `true`.